# loadModel() VS requestAction() VS constructClasses() .which is better and why?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.1

loadModel() VS requestAction() VS constructClasses() .

what is the difference ?which is better and why?

which one is preferred in which circumstances and why?

Comment: I dont think they actually can be compared. all three do something totally different and something unique to each situation. you have to use the one fitting this situation, not whats better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark already answered your question in the comment..this is a very invalid question! The three methods do three completely different things.

Even if the methods were doing the same thing, your question would still not make any sense - better for what? What are you trying to accomplish? Without context, this is the same as asking "Which one is better, eating ice-cream or being a milkman?